# Create table with 4 of 6 columns unique

Tags: sql, join

I have an original table that I create with a stored procedure. The resulting table is used in a number of queries so I really don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I have six columns in the table. What I need to do is create a view of this table where 4 columns as a set are unique and one of the remaining columns finds the max value based on that set.

For example:

```
col 1     col2     col3      col4     col 5     col 6
------------------------------------------------------
123       US       EA.COM    Good     5/1/12    456A
124       US       US.COM    Good     5/1/12    457A
124       US       EA.COM    Good     5/1/12    457A
124       US       EA.COM    Good     5/15/12   457A
```

With this set I would get 3 rows back

```
col 1     col2     col3      col4     col 5     col 6
------------------------------------------------------
123       US       EA.COM    Good     5/1/12    456A
124       US       US.COM    Good     5/1/12    457A
124       US       EA.COM    Good     5/15/12   457A
```

What I want is the unique set of cols 1-4 and the max of col5 then col 6 equivalent to the set of cols 1-5. I hope that this makes sense. I am outside my comfort zone at this level of SQL.

I have tried using temp tables and joining based on distinct values in cols 1- 4 but have not yet come up with the correct syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain more precisely what you mean by `then col 6 equivalent to the set of cols 1-5. `?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, max(col5), col6
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col6
```